Saving output from a function containing loop and ifelse
Basically I wan to be able to save a function output in numeric format into an R object. The function contains a loop and ifelse arguments which may contribute to my difficulties in achieving this.
I would like to create a function like the following:
fnct <- function(x, y) {
  for (i in x) {
    ifelse(i >= y[1] & i <= y[2], y[3], 
            ifelse(i < y[1], y[1], 
                    ifelse((max(x) - y[2] > y[1]), y[2], 
                           NA)))
  }
}

If I run this code, nothing happens.
fnct(c(1:150), c(20, 80, 50)) 

If I modify the code as follows by adding print arguments, I get an ouptut:
fnct <- function(x, y) {
  for (i in x) {
    ifelse(i >= y[1] & i <= y[2],
            print(y[3]),
            ifelse(i < y[1],
                    print(y[1]), ifelse((max(x) - y[2] > y[1]),
                                        print(y[2]),
                                        print(NA))))
  }
}

But I cannot save it to an r object.
I have also tried the following:
fnct <- function(x, y) {
  res <- matrix(nrow=length(x))
  for (i in x) {
    ifelse(i >= y[1] & i <= y[2],
            res[i] <- (y[3]),
            ifelse(i<y[1],
                   res[i] <- (y[1]), ifelse((max(x) - y[2] > y[1]),
                                           res[i] <- (y[2]),
                                           res[i] <- (NA))))
  }
  return(res)
}

which works in this case:
fnct(c(1:150), c(20, 80, 50)) 

but not for this:
fnct(seq(1.575, 5.125, by=0.05), c(1.5, 3, 3.5))


1. With a for loop.
You must create a vector where you save the ifelse results.
Also, note that the question's last ifelse does not depend on the index so it can be pre-computed.
fnct <- function(x,y) {
  out <- numeric(length(x))
  pre_comp <- ifelse(max(x) - y[2] > y[1], y[2], NA)
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    out[i] <- ifelse (x[i] >= y[1] & x[i] <= y[2],
            y[3],
            ifelse (x[i] < y[1],
                    y[1], pre_comp))
  }
  out
}
fnct(c(1:150),c(20,80,50))
#>   [1] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [26] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [51] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [76] 50 50 50 50 50 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
#> [101] 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
#> [126] 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0

2. With a *apply loop
The loop but with a *apply function becomes simpler, there is no need to create the results vector beforehand.
fnct <- function(x, y) {
  pre_comp <- ifelse(max(x) - y[2] > y[1], y[2], NA)
  sapply(x, \(xx) {
    ifelse (xx >= y[1] & xx <= y[2],
            y[3],
            ifelse (xx < y[1],
                    y[1], pre_comp))
  })
}
fnct(c(1:150),c(20,80,50))
#>   [1] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [26] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [51] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [76] 50 50 50 50 50 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
#> [101] 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
#> [126] 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0

Edit
Following user @lotus's comment I realized that the loop is not needed at all.
fnct <- function(x, y) {
  ifelse (x >= y[1] & x <= y[2],
          y[3],
          ifelse (x < y[1],
                  y[1], 
                  ifelse(max(x) - y[2] > y[1], 
                         y[2], NA)))
}
fnct(c(1:150),c(20,80,50))
#>   [1] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [26] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [51] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
#>  [76] 50 50 50 50 50 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
#> [101] 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
#> [126] 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0

Your last edit is simple and works, thank you very much!

Out of curiosity, if the last ifelse did depend on the index, how would you code it?
e.g.
ifelse((max(x)-y[2]>y[1]), (x[i]-y[3]), NA))

@cosalofa If it depends on the index you need a loop. But ifelse is vectorized, it evaluates each x[i] and decides which branch to take. (Actually, it creates a logical vector telling which of the yes or no alternatives to return.)

If the last ifelse did depend on the index, this seems to work:
    fnct <- function(x,y) {
              out <- numeric(length(x))
              for (i in seq_along(x)) {
                ifelse (x[i] >= y[1] & x[i] <= y[2],
                  out[i] <- y[3],
                        ifelse (x[i] < y[1],
                      out[i]<-  y[1], 
            ifelse((max(x)-y[2]>y[1]), 
                   out[i]<-(x[i]-y[3]), 
                   out[i]<-NA)))
              }
              out
            }
            fnct(c(1:150),c(20,80,50))

#>    [1]  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20
 #>    [20]  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50
#>     [39]  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50
#>     [58]  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50
#>     [77]  50  50  50  50  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
#>     [96]  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64
#>    [115]  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83
#>    [134]  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

